# spinner key and value

Tags: android, spinner

I am creating a translater app in which user need to choose the target language if suppose he choose marathi from the spinner then value for the marathi should be 'mr' so i can pass that value in url.
I have created a `spinner` and assigned languages from `strings.xml` but I want to use it's short form like for `hindi` the value should be `hi`, how can I achieve that?

```
    <string-array name="languages">
    <item>Marathi</item>
    <item>Hindi</item>
    <item>Japanese</item>
    <item>Russian</item>
    <item>Bengali</item>
    <item>Greek</item>
    <item>Gujarati</item>
    <item>Italian</item>
    <item>Malayalam</item>
    <item>German</item>
    <item>Punjabi</item>
    <item>Tamil</item>
    <item>Telugu</item>
    <item>French</item>
    <item>Urdu</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Can you explain the full use case ? More explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want substring?

Comment: create a Map instead of string array. Create that map in your java class and put these values in your map

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: It's like value and key but i don't know how to implement that

Comment: Use hash map for this purpose https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for map instead.

1-create the languages map

```
Map<String, String> languages = new HashMap<>();
        languages.put("hindi", "hi");
        languages.put("arabic", "ar");
        languages.put("english", "en");
```

2-get the selected item

```
    String selectedLanguage = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String languageToSend=languages.get(selectedLanguage); //send it to url
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Map object for your above functionality. You can create something like this.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Hindi", "Hi");
map.put("Marathi", "Mi");
```

You can reverse the order of the key and value according to your need. For populating your spinner you can get all the keys and put in a list and then add it to your spinner. You can do it like this

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by using Map as suggested by @Vivek Mishra (in comments) where key will be your language name to be displayed in spinner and value will be the language code you want to pass in URL.

Map will look something like below

```
languageMap.put ("Marathi","mr");
languageMap.put ("Hindi","hi");
```

Now when you want to use, get the String from the spinner, selected by User and get language code value by

```
languageMap.get("Marathi")
```

Another option to integrate with your current implementation, is to add language code array in String.xml in same order as language name array and get the same index from language code array as per the selected index of spinner.

```
<string-array name="languages_code">
    <item>mr</item>
    <item>hi</item>
    <!-- Add entries for other languages -->
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create tow list like

```
 List fullname= new ArrayList();
    fullname.add("hindia");
    fullname.add("persian");
    fullname.add("english");
 List urlName= new ArrayList();
    urlName.add("hin");
    urlName.add("per");
    urlName.add("eng");
```

then  add first one to spiner

```
   ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_dropdown, fullname);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
   // dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

finally with implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and and`spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` 
to  get equivalent value use below code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, 
long l) {
   String  url=urlName.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one string array with short names corresponding to languages array you already have, and fetched short language name by using position in "onItemSelected".

Following is a simplest way to achieve desired output:

**Strings.xml**

```
    <string-array name="languages">
        <item name="">Marathi</item>
        <item>Hindi</item>
        <item>Japanese</item>
        <item>Russian</item>
        <item>Bengali</item>
        <item>Greek</item>
        <item>Gujarati</item>
        <item>Italian</item>
        <item>Malayalam</item>
        <item>German</item>
        <item>Punjabi</item>
        <item>Tamil</item>
        <item>Telugu</item>
        <item>French</item>
        <item>Urdu</item>
    </string-array>
<string-array name="sr_languages">
        <item name="">Ma</item>
        <item>Hi</item>
        <item>Ja</item>
        <item>Ru</item>
        <item>Be</item>
        <item>Gr</item>
        <item>Gu</item>
        <item>It</item>
        <item>Ma</item>
        <item>Ge</item>
        <item>Pu</item>
        <item>Ta</item>
        <item>Te</item>
        <item>Fr</item>
        <item>Ur</item>
    </string-array>
```

**SpinnerActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sonias.stackoverflowdemos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner spLanguage;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> spAdapter;
    private String mSelectedLanguage = "";
    private ArrayList<String> LanguagesList;
    private ArrayList<String> srLanguagesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner);
        spLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spLanguage);
        LanguagesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages)));
        srLanguagesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sr_languages)));
        spAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SpinnerActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, LanguagesList);
        spLanguage.setAdapter(spAdapter);
        spLanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String mSelectedTExt = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
                mSelectedLanguage = srLanguagesList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "You have selected " + mSelectedTExt + " ( " + mSelectedLanguage + " )", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```